# get port used from BindException

Tags: java, exception

When getting a [`BindException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/BindException.html), is there a way to get which port is used? It seems to tell that there is a port which is already used, but not which one. That would be useful to speed up debugging.

Answer (score 2):

A BindException most often happens when your program is trying to bind to a port that is already being used. Unless your program is somehow selecting a random port, you should already know what your port is. Either kill the program running on the port in question or choose another port.

Comment: First sentence is not correct. There are two cases (at least): 'port in use' and 'cannot assign requested address'. I can't remember offhand what the message is when you run out of dynamic ports, but that is a possible third case. Or maybe it gives 'port in use: 0'.

Comment: You're right. It can also happen if it cannot bind to the address. My bad. However that doesnt seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be already there in the exception message ('port in use: xxx'), and in any case you can only bind to one port at a time, so you should already know which port you're trying to bind to.

However `BindException` can also be because the *bind-address* is wrong, i.e. non-local, in which case the message will be something like 'cannot assign requested address', which has nothing to do with the port number at all.